# Is there any way i can keep a check on a file, if it is being copied or is being used

Tags: android, linux, copy-paste

I am developing an android app to detect if someone is trying to forward a file via email or copying it through usb. So in android is there any api to check if a file is being copied. I know there is fileobserver api but it cannot check if a file is being copied is mailed.

Edit: i dont want to stop it from being read, i just want to stop it from being copies or used by any other app

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure it isn't read, put it in your private directory.  Otherwise other processes have full rights to read it, and once data is read there's no way to prevent it from being sent anywhere the app wants.